# Responsive Google Chart

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to make a Google chart  responsive but the rendered output looks like the following:
!the dates not showing correctly[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2H5o.png)
I can see the graph re-size but the content of the graph is not working probably, the chart content JSON data is working fine you can see the sample data attached with this json api.

I need some help make to make the text show correctly

here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "http://m.reporting.hero-leads.com/graph/campaign/0/0/4",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;  

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  // Set chart options
  var options = {
    'title':'Leads',
    'vAxis': {title: '# Leads',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}},
    'hAxis': {title: 'Days',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'},showTextEvery:1, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:90, minTextSpacing:1, textStyle:{color: '#333333', fontSize: 14},
    'width':(2*(window.innerWidth))/3,
    'height':(2*(window.innerHeight))/3,
    'legend':'bottom',
    'legendPosition':'sameRow'},
    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
    bar: { groupWidth: '30%' },
    colors: ['e46c0a','7f7f7f'],  
    isStacked: true,
    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' }
  };
   // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  function resize () {
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  window.onload = resize();
  window.onresize = resize;

}
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not an issue with resizing the chart - your hAxis options force the chart to draw labels close enough together that they overlap when the width of the chart gets narrow enough.  Use a smaller font size or remove the `showTextEvery` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using windows resize event

I have done this for semicircular pie chart.

Refer this

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/869927/Responsive-Semicircular-doughnut-Chart-Using-Googl

If you cant understand that refer following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(initChartExpertBottom);

$(window).on("resize", function (event) {
  initChartExpertBottom();
});

function initChartExpertBottom() {
  var options = {
    legend:'none',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    tooltip: { isHtml: true },
    chartArea: {left: "3%",top: "3%",height: "94%",width: "94%"},
    colors: ['#7CB5EC', '#5C5C61','#16c104'],
    pieHole: 0.50,
    pieStartAngle: -90,
    is3D: false,
    pieSliceText: 'none',
  };

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ["Hide" , (11+2)]                 //addition of value of all elements
  ]);
  drawChartExpertBottom(data, options);
}

function drawChartExpertBottom(data, options) {

  var tooltip = [
    Math.round((11/(11+2))*100) + "%",
    Math.round((2/(11+2))*100)+ "%",
    "Hiii3",
  ];

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

  var sliceid = 0;

  function eventHandler(e){
    chart.setSelection([e]);
    try {
      selection = chart.getSelection();
      sliceid = selection[0].row;
    }
    catch(err) {
      ;
    }
    $(".google-visualization-tooltip-item-list li:eq(0)").css("font-weight", "bold");
    $(".google-visualization-tooltip-item-list li:eq(1)").html(tooltip[sliceid]).css("font-family", "Arial");
  }


  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmousedown', eventHandler);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', eventHandler);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

HTML for above script

```
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Css for above code snippet

```
<style>
#piechart {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.google-visualization-tooltip{
  display:table;
}
g{
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
```